# What does "Check-in 1 piece" mean?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, virgin-australia

I have booked a one-way flight from Denpasar (DPS) to Sydney (SYD) via Adelaide. According to my e-ticket, the baggage allowance is:

`Baggage (per Adult/Child) – Check-in: 1 PIECE, Cabin: 7 KG`

What does "1 piece" mean exactly? How much baggage weight is allowed?

Comment: I'd wager (from an outsider's perspective) that it must be one piece of luggage (one container) not exceeding any of the definitions - which are defined in the answer by Nean Der Thal.

Comment: It also means that you're allowed one carry-on/hand-luggage/cabin-luggage item that can weigh up to 7Kg.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Virgin Australia](https://www.virginaustralia.com/nz/en/travel-info/baggage/checked-baggage/) the checked-in luggage allowance is 23kg, with a total linear dimension (length + width + height): 140cm (55in).

The luggage can exceed 23kg up to a maximum of 32kg for a fee depending on the flight route.

Comment: Note for future readers - Virgin Australia luggage depends on your ticket.  They have two types of economy fares now - Lite and Choice.  Lite does not include checked luggage.